# Searching a list collection in dotnet without looping

Tags: .net

Given the following class and declartion, assuming I've popupated myValues with instances of CellValue, is there an easy way of returning from myValues a cellValue whose RowID=1 and ColumnID=3

```
Class CellValue
    Public RowID, ColumnID As Integer
    Public Value As Object
End Class

Public myValues As List(Of CellValue)
```

Instead of looping through each element in myValues, is there a way to do something like:

dim x as CellValue = myValues.???(RowID=1, ColumnID=3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well *something* has to loop, but you could use the LINQ [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050) method or [`List(Of T).Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx), specifying a predicate.

For example:

```
Dim x = myValues.Find(Function(cell) cell.RowID = 1 AndAlso cell.ColumnId = 3)
```

Note that you should consider what you want to happen if no such cell can be found. `Find` will return the default value for `T` (presumably `Nothing`) in this case, and `FirstOrDefault` behaves the same way; `First` will throw an exception.

Comment: nvm.. that is the predicate method

Answer (score 1):

you can accomplish this with LinQ:

```
    Module Module1
        Public myValues As List(Of CellValue)
        Sub Main()
            myValues = New List(Of CellValue)

            myValues.Add(New CellValue With {.RowID = 1, .ColumnID = 1, .Value = "Hello 1"})
            myValues.Add(New CellValue With {.RowID = 2, .ColumnID = 2, .Value = "Hello 2"})
            myValues.Add(New CellValue With {.RowID = 3, .ColumnID = 3, .Value = "Hello 3"})
            myValues.Add(New CellValue With {.RowID = 4, .ColumnID = 4, .Value = "Hello 4"})
            myValues.Add(New CellValue With {.RowID = 5, .ColumnID = 5, .Value = "Hello 5"})

            Dim x As CellValue = (From val As CellValue In myValues Where val.RowID = 1 Select val).FirstOrDefault()

        End Sub

    End Module
    Class CellValue
        Public RowID, ColumnID As Integer
        Public Value As Object
    End Class
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have an array of objects in no particular order, any solution is going to involve looping through looking for the desired value.  Even if you use something like LINQ, the compiler generator code is still going to setup a loop construct.  This is just an *O(n)* operation.  There's a few ways to improve upon this:

**One: Sort your values**

If you keep you array in sorted order, you can use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) to locate your desired value.  This has the added cost of having to sort your array (and keep it sorted), but it can pay off for lookups.

**Two: Use a hash**

Your `CellValue` class can override [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) and return a distinct hash (such as `RowID ^ ColumnID`).  You can then use a `Dictionary<CellValue, CellValue>` class to store each value, and look up a certain cell in *O(1)* (provided there are no hash collisions).